# Javascript não funciona corretamente em IE e Mozilla

Tags: javascript, rolamento, animação

Olá possuo um código que faz uma animação na ancoragem do site. Quando o usuário clica no menu, ele faz a rolagem até o local ancorado. Porém só está funcionando de modo fluido no Chrome e no Opera. Como posso adaptá-lo para funcionar em todos os navegadores?

Código de Rolagem Animada com âncoras:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($(window).width() > 640) { 
  $(document).on("click", 'a[href*="#"]', function(e) {

    var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target
    target = target.substring(target.indexOf("#"), target.length);
    var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - 234;

    $('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': scrollToPosition }, 600, function(){
       window.location.hash = target;
    });

});

 $(document).ready(function() { 
   if(window.location.hash){ 
     $("a[href*='"+window.location.hash+"']") 
       .attr("onclick","this.click()") 
       .trigger("click") 
       .removeAttr("onclick"); 
   } });

}

  if ($(window).width() < 640) { 
  $(document).on("click", 'a[href*="#"]', function(e) {

    var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target
    target = target.substring(target.indexOf("#"), target.length);
    var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - 30;

    $('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': scrollToPosition }, 600, function(){
       window.location.hash = target;
    });

});

 $(document).ready(function() { 
   if(window.location.hash){ 
     $("a[href*='"+window.location.hash+"']") 
       .attr("onclick","this.click()") 
       .trigger("click") 
       .removeAttr("onclick"); 
   } });

}

</script>
```

Código que Fixa o Menu na tela:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    

if ($(window).width() > 640) {
   jQuery("document").ready(function($){
    var offset = $('.menu-bar').offset().top;
    var nav = $('.menu_component');

$(document).on('scroll', function () {
        if (offset <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
            nav.addClass('fixar');
        } else {
            nav.removeClass('fixar');
        }
    });

});
}


</script>
```

Sinto que além desse erro com a animação de scroll até as âncoras, o menu está dando uma bugada ao se fixar na tela.

Podem ver os scripts em funcionamento no site: https://sienpro.catalao.ufg.br/

Então gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com que isso funcione nos vários navegadores. Desde já agradeço!

Comment: quando vc colocar a classe `fixed` e `fixar` adicione tambem um `margin-top` na classe `.news-black`, para compensar a remoção dos blocos `.menu_component` e `.components_group_component` eu fiz um teste aqui é parece que seu problema é esse, como você muda o `position` para `fixed` ele perde a altura desse blocos e o restante da página sobe, ao menos aqui no mozila aparentemente é só isso, o script esta certo, apesar de que você consegue o mesmo efeito usando `position: sticky;`  que acho melhor e mais econômico

Comment: Como uso esse position sticky?

Comment: resolvi colocando o margin-top. parece q esse efeito é difícil com relação a compatibilidade

Comment: aqui tem uma explicação: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit é necessário eu adicionar uma resposta completa?